# the infimum of a set of outer measures defines again an outer measure

Tags: measure-theory

Consider a set of index $I$ . For each $i \in I$ consider an outer measure $\mu_i$. Prove that $ \mu=
\mathop {\inf }\limits_{i \in I} \mu _i 
$ defines an outer measure.
It's true with the supremum?

Clearly $\mu$ satisfies $\mu(\phi)=0$ and also satisfies $ A\subset B$ $\Rightarrow$ $ \mu(A) \le \mu(B)$ . It remains to prove the countably subadditive property.

Comment: I don't know how to start with this.... I'm very confused . For example , using the fact that every $\mu_i$ is an outer measure I can conclude the following $\mu_i(\cup {A_n}) \le \sum{\mu_i(A_n)}$ , thus I can conclude that $inf _{i\in I} {\mu_i(\cup {A_n})} \le inf{\sum{\mu_i(A_n)}}$ But I don't know how are related $ inf_{i\in I}{\sum{\mu_i(A_n)}} $ and ${\sum{inf_{i\in I}{\mu_i(A_n)}}}$

Comment: The statement is false: Consider $\Omega = \{a,b\}$ and $\mu_1(\{a\}) = 2 = \mu_1(\{b\})$, $\mu_1(\{a,b\}) = 3$ as well as $\mu_2(\{a\}) = 3$, $\mu_2(\{b\}) = 0$, $\mu_2(\{a,b\}) = 3$. Then $\mu_1,\mu_2$ define outer measures on $\Omega$, but $\mu_1 \wedge \mu_2$ is not an outer measure. - It works out with the supremum, though.

Comment: Thanks :D! you are welcome

Comment: @Thomas You could post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Done.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false: Consider $\Omega = \{a,b\}$ and $\mu_1(\{a\}) = 2 = \mu_1(\{b\})$, $\mu_1(\{a,b\})=3$ as well as $\mu_2(\{a\}) = 3$, $\mu_2(\{b\}) = 0$, $\mu_2(\{a,b\}) = 3$. Then $\mu_1, \mu_2$ define outer measures on $\Omega$, but $\mu_1 \wedge \mu_2$ is not an outer measure. - It works out with the supremum, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take $\bigwedge_\alpha \mu_\alpha := \sup \nu$ as the supremum measure taken over all the measures $\nu$ such that $\nu(A) \leq \inf_\alpha \mu_\alpha(A), \forall A \subset \Omega$. When you take a supremum over a non empty familly of outer measures (*why is it non empty, in this case?*) you get an outer measure, and from the definition you get $\bigwedge \mu_\alpha \leq \inf_\alpha \mu_\alpha$ and any measure that satisfies the last inequality must be smaller than our construction $\bigwedge_\alpha \mu_\alpha$.